# Getting this error when running the application

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here is the Error:

> Task :checkout:bootRun FAILED
> ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
> ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
> JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':checkout:bootRun'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Do you force debugger options in the build files? Do you run or debug your application? See if running directly instead of using Gradle helps: https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.